# how to use semantic UI React Checkbox toggle?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use Semantic UI react for layout. These are the following sample code I am having trouble with onChange. I can check to click the toggle but resets everytime I refresh.

```js
import {
  Checkbox
} from 'semantic-ui-react'

onChangeInput(event) {
    let name = event.target.name
    let value = event.target.value

    let talent = this.state.newTalentProfile
    talent[name] = value

    this.setState({
      newTalentProfile: talent
    })

  }
  
  <Select
name = "willing_to_relocate"
ref = "willing_to_relocate"
defaultValue = {this.props.talent.willing_to_relocate}
onChange = { this.onChangeInput.bind(this)} >
  <Option value = ""label = "" / >
  <Option value = "YES"label = "YES" / >
  <Option value = "NO"label = "NO" / >
  </Select>

the below code doesn't work, but the above one works when i make changes it saves it to database

<Checkbox toggle
name = "willing"
ref = "willing"
label = "Willin To Relocate"
onChange = {this.onChangeInput.bind(this)
}

/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  onChangeCheckbox = (evt, data) => {
    let checked = data.checked
    console.log(checked)
  }


 <Checkbox toggle label='Running discounted price?' 
  onClick={(evt, data)=>this.onChangeCheckbox(evt, data)}
   />
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your code suggests you expect `event.target` to be a checkbox element, but it is not. If you examine the variable `event.target` within your browser, you'll notice that it points to a `label` element, not the checkbox itself. Therefore, I'm guessing that your `event.target.value` and `event.target.label` are evaluating to `null`, causing the rest of your code to not function the way you expect.

There's many ways to get around this. One way is to set a state variable for your component to represent the state of the checkbox:

```
class TheComponentThatContainsMyCheckbox extends Component {
    state = {
     textValue: null,
     willingToRelocate: true
    }
...
```

Then, you can create a handler that toggles this state when checked:

```
toggleCheckBox = () => {
  const willingToRelocate = !(this.state.willingToRelocate);
  this.setState({willingToRelocate}); 
  // Note: if you have other logic here that depends on your newly updated state, you should add in a callback function to setState, since setState is asynchronous
}
```

Notice that I'm using arrow syntax here, which will automatically bind `this` for me. Then, hook it up to the `onChange` event of the Semantic UI Checkbox:

`<Checkbox label='Willing to Relocate.' onChange={this.toggleCheckBox}/>`

You can now use your `this.willingToRelocate` state to decide other application logic, passing it up or down using whatever state management pattern you like (state container/store like Redux, React Context, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `this.onChangeInput` handles database updates.

semantic ui react offers a prop `checked` for Checkbox.

You should have a state {checked: false} in your code, then `this.setState` whatever in componentDidMount after retrieving the database record.

Pass `this.state.checked` into `checked` prop of Checkbox.